# Why doesn't code acceleration work with Cython?

Tags: python, numpy, cython, bit

I need to speed up this code to 4 milliseconds.

```
import numpy as np



def return_call(data):
    num = int(data.shape[0] / 4096)
    buff_spectrum  = np.empty(2048,dtype= np.uint64)
    buff_detect =  np.empty(2048,dtype= np.uint64)
    end_spetrum = np.empty(num*1024,dtype=np.uint64)
    end_detect = np.empty(num*1024,dtype= np.uint64)
    _data = np.reshape(data,(num,4096))

    for _raw_data_spec in _data:
        raw_data_spec = np.reshape(_raw_data_spec,(2048,2))
        for i in range(2048):
            buff_spectrum[i] = (np.int16(raw_data_spec[i][0])<<17)|(np.int16(raw_data_spec[i][1] <<1))>>1
            buff_detect[i] = (np.int16(raw_data_spec[i][0])>>15)
        for i in range (511,-1,-1):
            if buff_spectrum[i+1024] != 0:
                end_spetrum[i]=(np.log10(buff_spectrum[i+1024]))
                end_detect[i]=buff_detect[i+1024]
            else:
                end_spetrum[i] =0
                end_detect[i] = 0
        for i in range(1023, 511, -1):
            if buff_spectrum[i+1024] != 0:
                end_spetrum[i] = (np.log10(buff_spectrum[i + 1024]))
                end_detect[i] = buff_detect[i + 1024]
            else:
                end_spetrum[i] = 0
                end_detect[i] = 0

    return end_spetrum, end_detect
```

I decided to use Cython for this task. But I didn’t get any acceleration.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy


ctypedef signed short DTYPE_t
cpdef return_call(numpy.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] data):
    cdef int i
    cdef int num = data.shape[0]/4096
    cdef numpy.ndarray _data

    cdef numpy.ndarray[unsigned long long, ndim=1] buff_spectrum  = np.empty(2048,dtype= np.uint64)
    cdef numpy.ndarray[ unsigned long long, ndim=1] buff_detect =  np.empty(2048,dtype= np.uint64)
    cdef numpy.ndarray[double , ndim=1] end_spetrum = np.empty(num*1024,dtype= np.double)
    cdef numpy.ndarray[double , ndim=1] end_detect = np.empty(num*1024,dtype= np.double)
    _data = np.reshape(data,(num,4096))

    for _raw_data_spec in _data:
        raw_data_spec = np.reshape(_raw_data_spec,(2048,2))
        for i in range(2048):
            buff_spectrum[i] = (np.uint16(raw_data_spec[i][0])<<17)|(np.uint16(raw_data_spec[i][1] <<1))>>1
            buff_detect[i] = (np.uint16(raw_data_spec[i][0])>>15)
        for i in range (511,-1,-1):
            if buff_spectrum[i+1024] != 0:
                end_spetrum[i]=(np.log10(buff_spectrum[i+1024]))
                end_detect[i]=buff_detect[i+1024]
            else:
                end_spetrum[i] =0
                end_detect[i] = 0
        for i in range(1023, 511, -1):
            if buff_spectrum[i+1024] != 0:
                end_spetrum[i] = (np.log10(buff_spectrum[i + 1024]))
                end_detect[i] = buff_detect[i + 1024]
            else:
                end_spetrum[i] = 0
                end_detect[i] = 0

    return end_spetrum, end_detect
```

The maximum speed I achieved is 80 milliseconds, but I need it much faster. Since you need to process data from iron in almost real time
Tell me the reason. And is it realistic to achieve the desired results. I also enclose the code for the test file.

```
import numpy as np
import example_original
import example_cython
data = np.empty(8192*2, dtype=np.int16)
import time
startpy = time.time()


example_original.return_call(data)
finpy = time.time() -startpy
startcy = time.time()
k,r = example_cython.return_call(data)
fincy = time.time() -startcy
print( fincy, finpy)
print('Cython is {}x faster'.format(finpy/fincy))
```

Comment: You need to profile your code to see what is slowing it down. Since it is all numpy, going to Cython may not help.

Comment: A few hints 1. You should probably turn off wraparound and boundschecking to speed up the indexing if numpy arrays (once you've carefully checked that you aren't relying on them). 2. Replace Numpy operations on single values with an equivalent `libc.math` operation. Definitely `log10` and probably also `np.int16` (but not sure what that should be replaced with). 3. Use `cython -a` to generate a useful annotated file.

Comment: This is what cython -a gave me.
Unfortunately, I am new to profiling, so if you tell me where to look and how to try to fix it, I will be grateful.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFlpY.png

Comment: This is slow iterative `numpy`.

Comment: but how can I speed it up because I did not find how to replace np.uint16 with C?

Comment: Try `from libc.stdint cimport uint16_t` and use `uint16_t` instead (but I haven't tested it...)

Comment: unfortunately example_cython.pyx: 24: 38: Calling non-function type 'uint16_t'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
raw_data_spec = np.reshape(_raw_data_spec,(2048,2))
```

`raw_data_spec` isn't typed. At the start of the function add a definition for it. I recommend the newer memoryview syntax (but use the old numpy syntax if you want):

```
cdef DTYPE_t[:,:] raw_data_spec
```

---

This line (which you have identified as a bottle-neck) is a mess:

```
buff_spectrum[i] = (np.int16(raw_data_spec[i][0])<<17)|(np.int16(raw_data_spec[i][1] <<1))>>1
```

1. Do indexing in one step, not two: `raw_data_spec[i, 0]` (note one lots of brackets and a comma).
2. Reconsider the cast to a 16 bit integer. Does it really make sense to be shifting a 16 bit integer by **17 bits**?
3. You probably don't need a cast at all since the data will be known to be `DTYPE_t`, but if you do do want a cast then use angle brackets: `<numpy.uint16_t>(raw_data_spec[i, 0])`

---

Consider turning off `boundscheck` and `wraparound`. **Verify to yourself that it's safe to do so** and that you aren't relying to exceptions to tell you when you're indexing beyond the end of an array, or using negative indexing. Only do this after thought - not automatically in a "cargo cult" way.

```
cimport cython    

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef return_call(numpy.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] data):
```

---

Ditch the calls to `np.log10`. This is a whole Python call on a single element, which ends up being inefficient. You can use the C standard library math functions instead:

```
from libc.math cimport log10
```

then replace `np.log10` with `log10`.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to speed things up with Cython. The main delays were in type conversion to uint 16.

Answer (score 2):

I think a major reason for this might be because your python code had almost no python operations and all of it was numpy operations. A large portion of the numpy code is written in C. Some of it is written in Fortran. A lot of it is written in Python. Well-written numpy code is comparable in speed to C code.

Comment: Actually is has a lot of Python operations - on numpy arrays.  There are several levels of `for` and indexed operations like `end_detect[i]=buff_detect[i+1024]`.  That's slow python, slower then if using lists.  The faster numpy comes into play when working with whole arrays, not individual elements of an array.

Comment: This kind of indexing is quick in Cython (if written correctly) so shouldn't be a problem in the compiled version. (Of course maybe it's possible that the whole thing could be vectorized avoiding the need for Cython...)

Comment: ``` for i in range(2048):
            buff_spectrum[i] = ((raw_data_spec[i][0])<<17)|((raw_data_spec[i][1] <<1))>>1
            buff_detect[i] = ((raw_data_spec[i][0])>>15)```
f you remove this part of the code, then Cython is 400 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have not much experience with Cython, so this is only an example what timings should also be possible with Cython.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def return_call(data_in):
    #If the input is not contigous the reshape will fail
    #-> make a c-contigous copy if the array isn't c-contigous
    data=np.ascontiguousarray(data_in)

    num = int(data.shape[0] / 4096)
    buff_spectrum  = np.zeros(2048,dtype= np.uint64)
    buff_detect =  np.zeros(2048,dtype= np.uint64)
    end_spetrum = np.zeros(num*1024,dtype=np.float64)
    end_detect = np.zeros(num*1024,dtype= np.float64)
    _data = np.reshape(data,(num,4096))

    #for _raw_data_spec in _data: is not supported
    #but the followin works
    for x in range(_data.shape[0]):
        raw_data_spec = np.reshape(_data[x],(2048,2))
        for i in range(2048):
            buff_spectrum[i] = (np.int16(raw_data_spec[i][0])<<17)|(np.int16(raw_data_spec[i][1] <<1))>>1
            buff_detect[i] = (np.int16(raw_data_spec[i][0])>>15)
        for i in range (511,-1,-1):
            if buff_spectrum[i+1024] != 0:
                end_spetrum[i]=(np.log10(buff_spectrum[i+1024]))
                end_detect[i]=buff_detect[i+1024]
            else:
                end_spetrum[i] =0
                end_detect[i] = 0
        for i in range(1023, 511, -1):
            if buff_spectrum[i+1024] != 0:
                end_spetrum[i] = (np.log10(buff_spectrum[i + 1024]))
                end_detect[i] = buff_detect[i + 1024]
            else:
                end_spetrum[i] = 0
                end_detect[i] = 0

    return end_spetrum, end_detect
```

**Timings**

```
data = np.random.rand(8192*2)*20
data=data.astype(np.int16)

#with compilation
%timeit end_spetrum, end_detect=return_call(data)
#32.7 µs ± 5.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#without compilation
%timeit end_spetrum, end_detect=return_call_orig(data)
#106 ms ± 448 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Yes, this method is good, but it always works at the same speed, at least at least with at least a large number of samples.